# Maintaining AWS Datastore subscription when app is closed

Tags: react-native, datastore, aws-amplify

This may be a general question, but I've only been able to find bits of an answer online.

I am using React Native and AWS Datastore to create a chat app that receives real-time updates through subscriptions.

What I would really like, is if the app could update the messages while in the background so that when a user opens the app the messages are already there. Is this possible? It seems from other forums that it is possible to keep a datastore subscription open when an app is closed, but I have not been able to make it work? Is IOS forcing the web-socket to close?

What is the best way to get something like this working?